# STL map onto itself?

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, containers

I'd like to create a `std::map` that contains a `std::vector` of iterators into itself, to implement a simple adjacency list-based graph structure.

However, the type declaration has me stumped: it would seem you need the entire map type definition to get the iterator type of said map, like so:

```
map< int, Something >::iterator MyMap_it;  // what should Something be?
map< int, vector<MyMap_it> > MyMap_t;
```

Is there some sort of partial map iterator type I can get with just the key type, so I can declare the full map?

Comment: Interesting..sounds like infinite recursion.

Comment: Just a circular pointer… there's no recursion unless map<>::iterator attempts to do something meaningful with its type argument. Which would be perfectly legal for it to do, just doesn't happen in GCC + SGI STL.

Comment: The problem is that he needs to define one of the two types first. Either the Map or the iterator. Since both need the other type for their declaration, the compiler cannot do it. Thus my solution to make a forward declaration of a new type so that the compiler will  let him create the Map.

Comment: The compiler can do it with templates instead of a forward declaration. See the previous revision of my answer. I only added the forward declaration for clarity.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could use forward declaration of a new type.

```
class MapItContainers;
typedef map<int, MapItContainers>::iterator MyMap_it;

class MapItContainers
{
public:
 vector<MyMap_it> vec;
};
```

With this indirection the compiler should let you get away with it.
It is not so very pretty but honestly I don't think you can break the self referencing easily.

Comment: gcc 4.4.1 appears to not barf on this, it even lets me create instances of `map<int, MapItContainers>`.

Comment: Probably because the iterator only uses pointers/references to the second template argument's type, so a forward declaration is enough.

Answer (score 5):

Not too ugly, considering…

This works in GCC 4.0.1 and compiles fine in Comeau strict mode.

The template definitions are parsed and deferred until they're instantiated. The compiler doesn't even see what a rec_map_iterator is until it's time to create one, by which time it knows how to do so ;v) .

```
template< class key >
struct rec_map;

template< class key >
struct rec_map_iterator : rec_map< key >::iterator {
    rec_map_iterator( typename rec_map< key >::iterator i)
    : rec_map< key >::iterator(i) {}
};

template< class key >
struct rec_map : map< key, vector< rec_map_iterator< key > > > {};
```

Here's the test program I used.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template< class key >
struct rec_map;

template< class key >
struct rec_map_iterator : rec_map< key >::iterator {
    rec_map_iterator( typename rec_map< key >::iterator i)
    : rec_map< key >::iterator(i) {}
};

template< class key >
struct rec_map : map< key, vector< rec_map_iterator< key > > > {};

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {
    rec_map< int > my_map;

    my_map[4];
    my_map[6].push_back( my_map.begin() );

    cerr << my_map[6].front()->first << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: +1 for frightening me. I would never use this in production code though, nasmorns solution is much simpler.

Comment: mine allows you to write simpler code besides the one-off trickery. Maybe less elegant, but I think it's more in the spirit of C++ ;v) .

Comment: Why wouldn't `template<class key> struct rec_map_iterator : rec_map<key>::iterator` require a `typename` in front of `rec_map<key>::iterator`? The same goes for the base initialization list. ( FWIW, como agrees with your GCC, but I don't see why it would.)

Comment: Initially I wrote it that way, and GCC complained that it /knew/ that was a typename because all base classes / base initializers are typenames. The strange thing is that member initializers look like base initializers but aren't typenames. Anyway, I'll take its word that it's enforcing the standard.

Comment: Would you need to be careful about the array/map notation when adding elements like "my_map[1].push_back(my_map.begin())"?  The order of evaluation may cause you to add something you didn't expect.

Comment: @PinkTriangles: Yes, you would. Note, however, that `my_map.begin()` does not necessarily refer to `my_map[1]`. You would have to do this in two steps anyway: 1) create entry: `my_map[1];` 2) insert iterator `my_map[1].push_back(my_map.find(1));`

Comment: @sbi: Since `insert()` only returns the element if it already exists, you can do `my_map[1].push_back( my_map.insert( make_pair( 1, rec_map<int>::mapped_type() ) ).first );`. Using lines still can enhance performance: ` rec_map<iterator> it = my_map.insert( make_pair( 1, rec_map<int>::mapped_type() ) ).first;
 it->push_back( it );
`

Comment: oops that should be `rec_map<int>::iterator it = …`

Comment: @Potatoswatter: That's a mean piece of code to put into one line, but I guess you're right and this should work. `:)` I suppose you presume the second to be faster because it eliminates the `my_map[1]` lookup?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Oh, and BTW, thanks for your explanations regarding `typename`. I would have thought that, if it is required, it is always required. This rule that it is only required where there could be something else than a type seems pretty arbitrary when you see the compiler warn that, what it interprets as an object, might meant to be a type, immediately followed by an error that there cannot be an object at this place...

Answer (score 2):

I didn't like deriving from a container in my previous answer so here's an alternative:

```
template< class key >
struct rec_map_gen {
    struct i;
    typedef map< key, vector< i > > t;
    struct i : t::iterator {
        i( typename t::iterator v )
        : t::iterator(v) {}
    };
};
```

Now you have to use `rec_map_gen<int>::t`, `rec_map_gen<int>::t::iterator`, etc, but you also have access to all `std::map`'s constructors. It's too bad C++ doesn't allow typedefs to be templated.

Using a derived iterator type should be OK. You can still initialize a reverse iterator from an element of this structure, for example.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Potatoswatter's answer, if you don't mind having to refer to the entire templated map type multiple times, you only need to subclass the iterator and don't need any pre-declarations:

```
template<class key>
struct rec_map_iterator : map<key, vector<rec_map_iterator<key> > >::iterator
{
    rec_map_iterator(typename map<key, vector<rec_map_iterator<key> > >::iterator i)
        : map<key, vector<rec_map_iterator<key> > >::iterator(i)
    {}
};
```

Then use the full type:

```
map<int, vector<rec_map_iterator<int>>> m;
```

Also, here's an update (my favorite so far) for C++11 by declaring rec_map as an alias, which can be templated:

```
template<class key>
struct rec_map_iterator;

template<class key>
using rec_map = map<key, vector<rec_map_iterator<key>>>;

template<class key>
struct rec_map_iterator : rec_map<key>::iterator
{
    rec_map_iterator(typename rec_map<key>::iterator i)
        : rec_map<key>::iterator(i)
    {}
};
```

This works the same as Potatoswatter's version:

```
rec_map<int> my_map;
```

Comment: This is similar to my *second* answer :) but the C++11 factoring is nicer.