# STL container to create and traverse a graph?

Tags: c++, graph, stl

i need to label all edges either back/forward/cross. For this i need to traverse the graph.

What container should i use? Possibly vector or map?

Comment: Something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403501/stl-map-onto-itself)?

Comment: how big is your graph? what are the values for the nodes? integers or strings? the best solution depends on these and what you later plan to do with it. you could just hold a vector of edges, each edge being a custom `struct`, or a [tuple](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/tuple/tuple/?kw=tuple)

Comment: graph is given as adjacency list, it is integers, there are at most 2^15 vertices labeled by unsigned ints!

Comment: Do you want your data structure to represent the *graph*? Or to represent the intermediary data necessary to label the graph?

Comment: yes, just represent the graph! as i traverse the graph using my data structure, it will just print the label: "edge 3-4 back edge" , "edge 1-2 cross edge" etc

Comment: Take a look at this nice blog post where it says how can we create a C++ graph using STL:
http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2014/02/creating-graph-using-stls-in-c.html

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
unordered_map<T, forward_list<T>> Graph;
```

where `T`: the node type of your graph. With this, you can reach any vertex in O(1) time, then traverse its edges on the `forward_list`.

Here: `unordered_map` is the hash map and `forward_list` is the linked list from STL.

Hope that helps!