# Best way to build this data structure

Tags: c++

I am interested in building an `std::unordered_map< K, V> Map;` where V is something like `Map::iterator`. Specifically I want to make V this `vector< Pair< double, Map::iterator> >;`
. As just stated this is a recursive type in C++ which is not allowed by the standard.

However, the operations of `begin()`, `end()` and `operator++()` on the unordered_map do not need any knowledge of `Map::mapped_type` to be well defined, so, in principle it seems that `Map::iterator` should be able to be defined independently of unordered_map.

So I wonder is there a way to define:

```
typedef std::unordered_map_iterator< K> iterator;
typedef std::unordered_map_const_iterator< K> const_iterator;
```

then create:

```
typedef std::unordored_map< K, iterator> Map;
```

such that, `map.insert( std::make_pair( K(), map.begin());` makes sense?

For example what about something like the below?

```
typedef std::unordered_map< K, V> Premap;
typedef std::unordered_map< K, Premap::iterator> Map;
```

In partial answer, the above suggestion produces a template deduction error, as expected. But nevertheless something like this should be do-able.

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <utility> 

typedef std::string K; //these two types are arbitrary
typedef double V; //chosen just for completeness sake.

typedef std::unordered_map< K, V> Premap;
typedef std::unordered_map< K, Premap::iterator> Map;

int main( int argc, char ** argv){

        Map test;
        test.insert( std::make_pair( std::string( "foo"), test.end()));
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1403546/44729)?

Comment: Such data structure keeps referring to its elements endlessly. What are you trying to do, a graph?

Comment: @genpfault yes, except an unordered_map is defined by the standard so I can't do this.

Comment: @MaximYegorushkin Maxim, yes it is true that an **algorithm** using this data structure can in principle walk around forever. This is for building something like a graph, sure. It's really for an algebraic construct, a chain complex.

Comment: @genpfault: Sorry, a bit presumptious, your solution actually would in principle work, if it actually compiled:

sim_map_test.cpp:4:7: error: forward declaration of ‘class MapItContainers’

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating a standard container which contains iterators to itself is impossible. However, there are alternative approaches which behave the same.

### Solution 1

`unordered_map` requires unique keys. Therefore, simply use `std::string` as the value type, and look it up in the map when necessary. The average algorithmic complexity of the lookup is the same in both cases - O(1).

Example: let's say you want to represent this data:

```
foo -> bar
bar -> baz
baz -> barney
fred -> (nothing)
barney -> (nothing)
```

Then you would write this to construct the data structure:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> Map;
Map m;
m.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("foo"), std::string("bar")));
m.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("bar"), std::string("baz")));
m.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("baz"), std::string("barney")));
m.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("fred"), std::string("")));
m.insert(std::make_pair(std::string("barney"), std::string("")));
```

To walk along the chains in this structure, you could use code like this:

```
Map::iterator i = m.find("foo");
while (i != m.end() && !i->second.empty()) {
    i = m.find(i->second);
}
```

Note that any string which does not appear as a key could be used to mark the end of the chain.

### Solution 2

Use `boost::ptr_unordered_set` and store the pointer to the next value in the value itself. Add appropriate equality and comparison operators, so that the pointer is ignored in the set. Note that this adds an extra level of indirection, but this is unavoidable.

```
struct ChainElement
    : boost::equality_comparable<ChainElement>
{
    std::string key;
    ChainElement *next;

    ChainElement(std::string const &k, ChainElement *n = NULL)
        : key(k), next(n)
    {}

    bool operator==(ChainElement const &other) const {
        return key == other.key;
    }
};

namespace std {
template <>
hash<ChainElement>::operator()(ChainElement const &ce) const {
    return std::hash(ce.key);
};
}
```

Set up the structure e.g. like this:

```
#include <boost/ptr_container/ptr_unordered_set.hpp>

// ...

boost::ptr_unordered_set<ChainElement> m;
m.insert(new ChainElement("foo"));
m.insert(new ChainElement("bar"));
m.insert(new ChainElement("baz"));
m.insert(new ChainElement("fred"));
m.insert(new ChainElement("barney"));
m.find("foo")->next = &*m.find("bar");
m.find("bar")->next = &*m.find("baz");
m.find("baz")->next = &*m.find("barney");
```

Then to walk the structure:

```
ChainElement *elem = &*m.find("foo");
while (elem != NULL) {
    // do something
    elem = elem->next;
}
```

Using `boost::ptr_unordered_set` rather than `std::unordered_set` guarantees that the objects will be deleted when the container holding them is deleted.

Comment: sorry, how is this a solution? can you provide your solution in the form of a small test code that contains something like: test.insert( std::make_pair( std::string( "foo"), test.end())); which compiles correctly?

Comment: Hi, yes, I understand this is something one can do, but it is not the same thing. I want to avoid all those finds.

Comment: The finds are O(1) - they have the same algorithmic complexity as following pointers. I have a different solution which does what you want, I'll write it up separately.

Comment: I accepted this answer even though I think something like what genpfault was saying is really the "correct" solution. I realize that what I want to do is not exactly what I was doing.

Comment: In that solution, a second container is used to store the iterators to the first one. You could make a set and a map with iterators to the set, but this wouldn't avoid the finds. Storing iterators to the container in the container itself is not possible.