# How to declare a self-referential container in C++?

Tags: c++, containers, typedef, self-reference

For a `typedef` of a `struct` in C, I can't do this:

```
typedef struct {
    unsigned id;
    node_t *left;
    node_t *right;
} node_t;
```

because `node_t` is not known until it is defined, so it can't be used in its own definition. A bit of a Catch-22. However, I can use this workaround to make the desired self-referential type:

```
typedef struct node_s node_t;
struct node_s {
    unsigned id;
    node_t *left;
    node_t *right;
};
```

Similarly, I would like to do something like this for a C++ container referring to itself:

```
typedef pair<unsigned, pair<node_t *, node_t * > > node_t;
```

but of course, the compiler complains that it's never heard of `node_t` before it's defined `node_t`, as it would for the `struct typedef` above.

So is there a workaround like for the `struct`? Or some better way to do this? (And no, I don't want to use `void` pointers.)

Comment: Does this help: [STL map onto itself?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1403501/stl-map-onto-itself)

Comment: You can look at realization of http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/variant/recursive_variant.hpp or http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/variant/recursive_wrapper.hpp

Comment: Your first case is a non-problem in C++: `struct node_t { node_t* left' node_t* right; };` is perfectly fine. Also, `std::pair` is not a container.

Comment: Ah, sorry. I was going by the [Wikipedia STL page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) which says that `pair` is a "simple container". And yes, I know that the first case is not a problem in C++, which is why I clarified with "in C".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
struct node_t : std::pair<unsigned, std::pair<node_t *, node_t * > >
{};
```

After `struct node_t` the compiler knows that the type with name `node_t` exists, similar to a forward declaration.

Answer (score 4):

The language does not support forward declaration of `typedef`s. Hence, you cannot use:

```
typedef pair<unsigned, pair<node_t *, node_t * > > node_t;
```

You can accomplish the notion of a *container* using `struct node_t {...};`, which I am sure needs no elaboration.

Answer (score 1):

You can self-reference a struct pointer *if you name it* (i.e. `typedef struct <name> {...}`). I usually use the following idiom:

```
typedef struct _node_t { // "Temporary" name "_node_t"
    unsigned id;
    struct _node_t *left; // Have to use "struct _node_t"
    struct _node_t *right;
} node_t; // "Final" name
```

That basically applies the previous answers to actual code.